# Ensime plugin causes sbt error: "You must explicitly set JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME"

Tags: java, ensime

> Spacemacs: 0.200.7
>
> Emacs: 25.3.1
>
> sbt: 1.2.0
>
> Java: openjdk version
>   "1.8.0_171"
>
> .sbt/1.0/plugins/plugins.sbt: addSbtPlugin("org.ensime" % "sbt-ensime"
>   % "2.5.1")
>
> scalaVersion 2.12.6

I have tried this with JAVA_HOME set or with using update-alternatives to specify a Java version. Initially, I had believed this was due to using an unsupported version of Java (Ensime doesn't support Java 9+) but switching to Java 8 doesn't resolve my issue.

Here's the trace:

> [info] Loading settings for project global-plugins from plugins.sbt,.#plugins.sbt,idea.sbt ...
>   [info] Loading global plugins from /home/myuser/.sbt/1.0/plugins
>   [info] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/home/myuser/.sbt/1.0/plugins/"), "global-plugins")...
>   [info] Done updating.
>   [error] java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not automatically find the JDK home.
>   [error] You must explicitly set JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME.
>   [error]         at org.ensime.EnsimePlugin$.$anonfun$JdkDir$6(EnsimePlugin.scala:694)
>   [error]         at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>   [error]         at org.ensime.EnsimePlugin$.JdkDir$lzycompute(EnsimePlugin.scala:693)
>   [error]         at org.ensime.EnsimePlugin$.JdkDir(EnsimePlugin.scala:681)
>   [error]         at org.ensime.EnsimePlugin$.$anonfun$buildSettings$20(EnsimePlugin.scala:199)
>   [error]         at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>   [error]         at org.ensime.EnsimePlugin$.$anonfun$buildSettings$19(EnsimePlugin.scala:199)
>   [error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
>   [error]         at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:221)
>   [error]         at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:164)
>   [error]         at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.$anonfun$submitEvaluate$1(INode.scala:87)
>   [error]         at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.sbt$internal$util$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:98)
>   [error]         at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:94)
>   [error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   [error] java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not automatically find the JDK home.
>   [error] You must explicitly set JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME.
>   [error] Use 'last' for the full log.
>   Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that ensime requires the `src.zip` file to be in the `JAVA_HOME` directory, the error message is misleading.

On Ubuntu 16.04 and with Java 8 you can get this by running `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-source`. It's probably something similar on other OSes.

Comment: This is correct. I had forgotten I had posted this questions, but resolved my issue with:
zypper in java-1_8_0-openjdk-devel